# Неверная обработка результатов SELECT в php

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю выборку из БД. Команда `print mysql_num_rows($res);` говорит что в ответе 3 строки - как и должно быть. Но в `json` выводится только самая первая. Что я делаю не так?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dialog_".$_POST['login']."_".$_POST['who']."";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        print mysql_num_rows($res);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $dialogs["id"] = $row['id'];
            $dialogs["from_login"] = $row['from_login'];
            $dialogs["message_enc_from_key"] = $row['message_enc_from_key'];
            $dialogs["who_login"] = $row['who_login'];
            $dialogs["message_enc_who_key"] = $row['message_enc_who_key'];
            $dialogs["date_time"] = $row['date_time'];

        }
        echo json_encode($dialogs);
```

Comment: *выводится только самая первая* - должна в вашем коде выводиться самая **последняя**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы каждый раз переписываете один и тот же массив — одни и те же ключи

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dialog_".$_POST['login']."_".$_POST['who']."";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    print mysql_num_rows($res);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $dialog = array();
        $dialog["id"] = $row['id'];
        $dialog["from_login"] = $row['from_login'];
        $dialog["message_enc_from_key"] = $row['message_enc_from_key'];
        $dialog["who_login"] = $row['who_login'];
        $dialog["message_enc_who_key"] = $row['message_enc_who_key'];
        $dialog["date_time"] = $row['date_time'];
        $dialogs[] = $dialog;
    }
    echo json_encode($dialogs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаётся переменная `$dialogs`, которой на каждой итерации присваивают только один набор.
Вынесете создание переменной вне цикла, создавайте в цикле очередной объект и **добавляйте** его в общий результат.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dialog_".$_POST['login']."_".$_POST['who']."";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$dialogs = []; // Создание переменной
print mysql_num_rows($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $tmp = []; // Временная переменная для текущей итерации
    $tmp["id"] = $row['id'];
    $tmp["from_login"] = $row['from_login'];
    $tmp["message_enc_from_key"] = $row['message_enc_from_key'];
    $tmp["who_login"] = $row['who_login'];
    $tmp["message_enc_who_key"] = $row['message_enc_who_key'];
    $tmp["date_time"] = $row['date_time'];
    $dialogs[] = $tmp; // Заполненную переменную добавляем в общий результат
}
echo json_encode($dialogs);
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, делал замену в `Sublime Text`, видимо глюканул, исправил.